# How to set a field example value when using python Flask-Restful+apispec+marshmallow?

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restful, marshmallow

I'm using flask to create an web application. I want to generate an API reference doc with swagger.
libraries: Flask-Restful, apispec, marshmallow (maybe also webargs)

I am able to generate a swagger page with most of my requirements, but I don't know how to set an example for a field. Have read official docs of these libraries, but didn't find where to set an example value of field.

Expected result:
[Expected result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuk5u.png)

[Expected result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs8Fg.png)

my result: (no example value)
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWgXO.png)

my code:

```
# request_schema.py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class RequestSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)      # want to set an example value here
```

```
# app.py
from flask_apispec import use_kwargs
from flask_apispec.views import MethodResource

from request_schema import RequestSchema
from flask_restful import Resource

class Restful_Request(MethodResource, Resource):
    @use_kwargs(RequestSchema(many=True), location='json')
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it in field metadata.

```
class RequestSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True, metadata={"example": "Whatever"})
```